# show line breaks in output

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

when i enter text into a text area with linebreaks this is not being output later when i display the text. how do i let it show the line spaces?, instead all the text is cramped together at the moment.

Comment: How are you storing the text? How are you displaying the text later?

Comment: Im using Razor which html encoodes it. eg @item.Description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked:

```
MvcHtmlString.Create(Model.Post.Description.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />"))
```

Answer (score 3):

How do you display it? HTML ignores whitespace, including line breaks. You can replace the linebreaks with the `<br>` element to show the enters in your browser too.

Mind that any subsequent spaces are also ignored. You can use the `<pre>` element too, to display the exact text, but I think that long lines won't be wrapped in that case.

Answer (score 1):

If you are putting your text into HTML try this just before writing it out to the page:

```
string myText = "" // your text
myText = myText.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br/>");
```

Comment: That's it, I was writting the same post as you

Comment: That didnt work it was displaying <br /> in the text. this worked: MvcHtmlString.Create(Model.Post.Description.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />")).... although really not happy about having to do this. is there a better or "standard" way built into razor?

Comment: The reason why it didn't work is because there is still processing of the string after you have done the Replace on it. The Replace should be the very last thing before the string is rendered to the output. I haven't used Razor so I'm not exactly sure where to look for this 'moment'.

Comment: Create your own helper or regular extension method. Make it as terse as you like. You can use Html.Raw to cut down on explicitly creating a MvcHtmlString